# sparklyr: skip first lines of text files

Tags: r, csv, apache-spark, sparklyr

I would like to skip (dropping out) the first two lines of a text file:
to the best of my knowledge this is not possible with sparklyr method `spark_read_csv`. There is some workaround to solve this simple problem?

I know the existance of [sparklyr extension](http://spark.rstudio.com/extensions.html) but i'm searching for a "more" standard way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom reader with function `spark_reader` introduced in version `1.3.0`. [API reference](https://spark.rstudio.com/reference/spark_read.html).

Let's see an example. Supose you have 2 files:

`sample1.csv` contains:

```
# file 1 skip line 1
# file 1 skip line 2
header1,header2,header3
row1col1,row1col2,1
row2col1,row2col2,1
row3col1,row3col2,1
```

`sample2.csv` contains:

```
# file 2 skip line 1
# file 2 skip line 2
header1,header2,header3
row1col1,row1col2,2
row2col1,row2col2,2
row3col1,row3col2,2
```

The following code reads the files from a local filesystem but the same can be applied to a HDFS source.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

paths <- paste("file:///", 
               list.files(getwd(), pattern = "sample\\d", full.names = TRUE), 
               sep = "")
paths
```

Paths must be absolute, in my example:`"file:///C:/Users/erodriguez/Documents/sample1.csv" ...`. Then the schema is defined with the data types. The `custom_csv_reader` is the reader function which gets a URI and returns a dataframe. The reader tasks will be distributed across Spark worker nodes. Note the `read.csv` call has argument `skip = 2` to drop first two lines.

```
schema <- list(name1 = "character", name2 = "character", file = "integer")

custom_csv_reader <- function(path) {
  read.csv(path, skip = 2, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

data <- spark_read(sc, path = paths, reader = custom_csv_reader, columns = schema)

data
```

Result:

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 3]
  name1    name2     file
  <chr>    <chr>    <int>
1 row1col1 row1col2     1
2 row2col1 row2col2     1
3 row3col1 row3col2     1
4 row1col1 row1col2     2
5 row2col1 row2col2     2
6 row3col1 row3col2     2
```